# Encrypt credentials for Wordpress XML-RPC API call

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption, xml-rpc, password-encryption

I'm planning to use [Wordpress' XML-RPC API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) but this requires me to store plain text username/password.

Is there a way to get a token from the Wordpress server so that I can store that instead of credentials to the db? Or securely encrypt the password before adding it to the db?

I'm using [this PHP library](https://github.com/letrunghieu/wordpress-xmlrpc-client).

Answer (score 1):

Try the method described in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/25792/57301 for securely storing API credentials in the WordPress database.